# Laravel post route returning error 500

Tags: laravel, routes

my route

```
Route::post('register', function()
{
    return "POST SUCCESS!";
});
```

works fine if I chane it to "get".
As soon as I change it to post (and use postman to actually send a post request) I get an error 500.
Its driving me crazy and I cant find the answer..

There is also nothing in the php error log... o_0

Comment: which version? L4 or L5?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Make sure you have created `.env` file for local environment.
2. Take a look at storage/logs/laravel.log, you should find error there, e.g.:

```shell
cat storage/logs/laravel.log | grep "\[201
```

Comment: tokenMismatchException

Comment: most probably you forgot to insert ``<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">`` to your form.

Comment: what if I'm making a post request without a form, with ajax or something else... api-style

Comment: If I understand this correctly. CSRF is mostly used for form data. If I have a RESTful API , is it safe to turn it off?

Comment: @Pero44 if you're happy with my answer you can accept it.